# Drawing from truncated normal distribution delivers wrong standard deviation in R

Tags: r, random, distribution, normal-distribution

I draw random numbers from a truncated normal distribution. The truncated normal distribution is supposed to have mean 100 and standard deviation 60 after truncation at 0 from the left. 
I computed an algorithm to compute the mean and sd of the normal distribution prior to the truncation (mean_old and sd_old).
The function vtruncnorm gives me the (wanted) variance of 60^2. However, when I draw random variables from the distribution, the standard deviation is around 96. 
I don't understand why the sd of the random variables varies from the computation of 60.

I tried increasing the amount of draws - still results in sd around 96.

```
 require(truncnorm)
 mean_old = -5425.078
 sd_old = 745.7254
 val = rtruncnorm(10000, a=0,  mean = mean_old, sd = sd_old)
 sd(val)
 sqrt(vtruncnorm( a=0,  mean = mean_old, sd = sd_old))
```

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want? You're basically asking for the very tail of Gaussian distribution - right tail beyond 7 sigma! In non-truncated gaussian probability to find values beyond 6 sigma is one over half-a-billion

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of this. However, I need this for my computations.

Comment: If I remember grad school correctly, it's pretty easy to use importance sampling to effectively draw from the tail of a Gaussian. [This source looks promising](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~owen/mc/Ch-var-is.pdf), but there are plenty of others if you search for "importance sampling tail of gaussian".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I did quick test

```
require(truncnorm)

val = rtruncnorm(1000000, a=7.2,  mean = 0.0, sd = 1.0)
sd(val)
sqrt(vtruncnorm( a=7.2,  mean = 0.0, sd = 1.0))
```

Canonical truncated gaussian. At a=6 they are very close, 0.1554233 vs 0.1548865 f.e., depending on seed etc. At a = 7 they are systematically different, 0.1358143 vs 0.1428084 (sampled value is smaller that function call). I've checked with Python implementation

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import truncnorm

a, b = 7.0, 100.0

mean, var, skew, kurt = truncnorm.stats(a, b, moments='mvsk')

print(np.sqrt(var))

r = truncnorm.rvs(a, b, size=100000)
print(np.sqrt(np.var(r)))
```

and got back 0.1428083662823426 which is consistent with R vtruncnorm result. At your a=7.2 or so results are even worse.

Moral of the story - at high `a` values sampling from rtruncnorm has a bug. Python has the same problem as well.

Comment: The Python bug seems to be identified [in this issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2477), which hadn't seen much activity for year, but now looks to have a pending pull request to fix.

Comment: @Gregor Yep, inverse transformation might fell for such regions. Frankly, I don't know how to fix it, would revisit it later